# Geometry and vectors: finding the scalar

Tags: geometry

[image]

This is a practice question (the black pen on the left) about vectors and in my first attempt (the black pen on the right) I tried using simultaneous equations by comparing coefficients. My second method (in green) was using Menelaus’s theorem and I got a different answer. I’m pretty certain that the method using Menelaus’s theorem is correct, but could anyone tell me where the first method went wrong and how you would tackle this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compared coefficients incorrectly near the end of your working;
$$-3t=-2-k$$ 
$$t=\frac23+\frac{k}3=2k\implies k=\frac25$$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for that!